# "Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found" exception in Sitecore 9

Tags: content-search, configuration

Sometimes when we change config file or deploy new code, we see this exception on first load of page:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

> Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException: Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [IndexNotFoundException: Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found]
>      Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name) +127
>      Sitecore.Marketing.Search.BaseDefinitionSearchProvider`2..ctor(String indexName) +91
>      Sitecore.Marketing.Search.ProfileDefinitionSearchProvider..ctor(IDefinitionManagerSearchSettings searchSettings) +113
>      System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) +339
>      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) +116
>      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) +111
>      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider) +116
>      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider provider) +69
>      Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager() +84
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4() +69
>      System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +737
>      System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +431
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues() +80
>      System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +737
>      System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +431
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles() +106
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField) +133
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item) +106
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ProfileUtil.GetProfiles(Item item, TrackingField& trackingField) +41
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.RenderProfileCardIcons(Item item, HtmlTextWriter output, Boolean& hasCardsConfigured) +128
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.RenderProfileCards(Item item, HtmlTextWriter output) +570
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.OnInit(EventArgs e) +260
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +460
>      System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +225
>      System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +245
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.AddControl(Control parent, Control control, String placeholder) +234
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs args, Control parent) +283
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item item, Item root, Control editorsContainer, Boolean showEditor) +291
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +487
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +568
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +212
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>     System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
>      Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +143
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7574

When we refresh the page, everything is working as expected.

Has anybody encountered similar issues?

How we can prevent this happening?

Comment: Are you doing deployments on Azure ?

Comment: This is in local machine so on premise.

Comment: Yes, I also have the same issue, but still don’t know how can we resolve it.

Comment: What if you go to Control Panel > and then in Indexing you run Populate Solr Managed Schema. After that, try rebuilding the indexes. Also, it's worth trying redeploying Marketing Definitions

Comment: I am also getting this error every time I change a config and reload my CD server. Mine is for sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web though not _master. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was getting this too and had to restart IIS so that I could log back in to Sitecore again.

Comment: Did you already report it to Sitecore Support?

Comment: You will be able to find this index configurations in Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Master.config, in case of solr. same way there is another config for Lucene and Azure. If you look at this config then it has Manual Index Strategy. So you must have to rebuild this index. It might be possible that after deployment, you directly hit the site URL which might not initialize the sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index.

Please try to load content editor and rebuild this index first, after deployment.

Comment: @NSP - But how is it possible that after hitting F5 on page no exception is raised and everything as expected without rebuild of index. Myself and couple of other folks based on comments see this exception only once during start up and after refresh no errors...

Comment: @TamasVargaSitecore I haven't reported so far to Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the index is not initialized. Adding the following to the *marketingDefinitionSolrIndexConfiguration* should fix it:

```
<initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
```

Since the question was about a developer machine, the initial answer does not apply:

<s>Can you check whether you have this configuration in your delivery server?</s>

```
<searchIndexName patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.Search.config">sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master</searchIndexName>
```

<s>On the delivery systems, this should probably point to *sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web*. The line should be in the file *Sitecore.Marketing.Search.config*.</s>

Comment: This is on the dev machine and as I mentioned after refresh everything's alright.

Comment: Does adding <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd> to the marketingDefinitionSolrIndexConfiguration fix it?

Comment: Adding  <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd> fixes it for me.

Comment: I am using sitecore 9.0 update 2 and adding the <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd> fixed my issue on my CD environment.

Comment: Seems like this is a bug since it happens on vanilla installs.

Comment: Can any 1 let me know the file name , path and syntax to add initializeOnAdd=true

Answer (score 0):

Same. Plain vanilla install of 9.1 and getting these index errors. Will get to the bottom of it...

Also wondering why all the configs are enabled by default - We are doing the default Solr install so surprised to see the Azure and Lucene configs in there. Possibly there is a setting that disables them when Solr is being used, but Sitecore configs used to be disabled if they weren't active, so this is a bit confusing. I am changing the names to .disabled just to be sure it isn't one of these other configs causing the error, as there are mentions of these indexes in all the configs

Comment: You no longer disable configs for search. You define the role now, like <add key="search:define" value="Solr"/>. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-a-search-and-indexing-provider.html